# Akka.actor.default-dispacher New connection accepted but http call not works

Tags: c, scala, http, akka-http

In scala, We are calling akka http API from the client code written in C. But when we call the API it only prints **akka.actor.default-dispatcher new connection accepted** but actual data transfer over http call (request response) not happens. Only connection happens with the client.

When we do same with postman the actual request came in actor and get processed. What should be the solution to get the http API works.

Comment: As far as I understand your post, this is an issue with your client code, not an issue with the API. However you'll have to share more details to get help: how your client code looks like..

Comment: @GaëlJ the whole code and API were working till yesterday from last 2 years..don't know what happened midnight 12 AM and Our APIs giving above error.

Comment: HTTP API is working just fine. The issue is somewhere in your client or network. Watch out for any recent changes which might have impacted it. Check for any library updates. Also take a look at your network situtation.

Comment: "but actual data transfer over http call (request response) not happens" - double check whether akka http generates the response. Log the response, response time, something like that. That may help: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequestResult.html?language=java if it responds but the responses doesn't get through to the client then the problem is elsewhere as Gael and Sarveshseri pointed out.

Comment: problem is with client using TLS V1.1 and that got unsupported so what needs to be done on server side to get support by TLS v1.1?

Comment: Look at these links: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.1.2/server-side/server-https-support.html#ssl-config 
https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/Protocols.html maybe all you need to do is updating your application.conf